# Export multiple images in one byte array (BLOB IBM DB2) to disk

Tags: java, c#, db2, websphere, blob

I have a column "Content" (BLOB data) in database (IBM DB2) and the data of an record same that (https://drive.google.com/file/d/12d1g5jtomJS-ingCn_n0GKMsM4RkdYzB/view?usp=sharing)
I have opened it by editor and I think that it has more than one image in this (https://i.stack.imgur.com/2biLN.png, https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwBOs.png).

I can export an image from byte array (using C#) to my disk, but with multiple images, I don't know how to do it.

Please help me! Thanks!

Edit 1:
I have tried export it as only one image by this code:

```
 private void readBLOB(DB2Connection conn, DB2Transaction trans)
    {
        try
        {
            string SavePath = @"D:\\MyBLOB";
            long CurrentIndex = 0;
            //the number of bytes to store in the array  
            int BufferSize = 413454;

            //The Number of bytes returned from GetBytes() method  
            long BytesReturned;

            //A byte array to hold the buffer  
            byte[] Blob = new byte[BufferSize];

            DB2Command cmd = conn.CreateCommand();

            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT ATTR0102500126 " +
                              "  FROM JCR.ICMUT01278001 " +
                              "  WHERE COMPKEY = 'N21E26B04900FC6B1F00000'";
            cmd.Transaction = trans;

            DB2DataReader reader;
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess);

            if (reader.Read())
            {
                FileStream fs = new FileStream(SavePath + "\\" + "quang canh.jpg", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
                BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(fs);

                //reset the index to the beginning of the file
                CurrentIndex = 0;

                BytesReturned = reader.GetBytes(
                    0, //the BlobsTable column index
                    CurrentIndex, // the current index of the field from which to begin the read operation
                    Blob, // Array name to write the buffer to
                    0, // the start index of the array
                    BufferSize // the maximum length to copy into the buffer
                    );

                while (BytesReturned == BufferSize)
                {
                    writer.Write(Blob);
                    writer.Flush();

                    CurrentIndex += BufferSize;
                    BytesReturned = reader.GetBytes(0, CurrentIndex, Blob, 0, BufferSize);
                }

                writer.Write(Blob, 0, (int)BytesReturned);
                writer.Flush(); writer.Close();

                fs.Close();
            }
            reader.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
```

But can not view the image, it show format error => https://i.stack.imgur.com/PNS9Q.png

Comment: "Interlacing" is a process where multiple copies of the image are stored in one file, starting with a low quality one at first. That way someone that only downloaded the first end of the file would be able to already see something - and check if it is the right file: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interlacing_(bitmaps) | Basically all modern file formats support interleaving - maybe that is what you are seeing in the raw data?

Comment: I'm not sure because I don't know the detail of it, I'm just guessing :( If that, have any solution that can export these images to my disk?

Comment: Have you tried just exporting one and see if a image processing programm can make sense of it? Are there any extensions/file formats stored with that raw data? Any indication in the header what formats they are suppose to be?

Comment: You did not write any code. Also you did not tell if the result was a readable image.

Comment: I have tried export it as only one image (as the content that I have edited above) but can not view image

Comment: "Does not work" has never been a sufficient problem description. What is the extension indicated by the rest of the table or the file header? What Image processing programm did you try? What happened or did not happen?

Comment: The extension of image is jpg (I sure that when edit data by editor), and this is image file that I have exported (https://drive.google.com/file/d/179afX8Elz_mBa-Etmv81wAZ9N36W4lr8/view?usp=sharing). When open by Photos of Win 10, it show error "It looks like we don't support this file format"  https://i.stack.imgur.com/PNS9Q.png

Comment: with my code above, it can export successfully if data of record have only one image, if it is a binary stream (multiple images), it is not success

Answer (score 0):

Your are currently asuming all BLOBS in that DB are JPEG Images. But that is clearly not the case.

**Option 1: This is a faulty data**

Programms that save to databases can fail.

Databases themself might fail, especially if transactions are turned off. Transactions are most likely turned off for BLOB's.

The physical disk the data was stored on might have degraded. And again, you will not get a lot of redundancy and error correction with BLOBS (plus getting use of the Error correction requires going through the proper DBMS in the first place).

**Option 2: This is not a jpg**

I know article about [Unicode](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/) that says "[...]problem comes down to one naive programmer who didn’t understand the simple fact that if you don’t tell me whether a particular string is encoded using UTF-8 or ASCII or ISO 8859-1 (Latin 1) or Windows 1252 (Western European), you simply cannot display it correctly or even figure out where it ends."

This applies doubly, triply and quadruply to images:

- this could be any number of formats that uses [Interlacing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interlacing_(bitmaps)).
- this could could be a professional graphics programms image/project file like [TIFF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TIFF#Multiple_subfiles). Which can totally contain multiple images - up to one per layer you are working with.
- this could even be a [.SVG file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics) (XML text that contains drawing orders) that was run through a .ZIP compression and a word document
- this could even be a PDF, where the images are usually appended at the back (allowing you to read the text with a partial file, similar to interleaving)

Comment: I sure that the data is not fault because I can view these images over my IBM Websphere Portal (and unicode is UTF-8) . But my purpose is convert data of this portal (IBM DB2) to another database (SQL Server), so that I need export all information from old DB. I can export title, content, thumb image,... of NEWS on portal, but these images, I can not :(

Comment: @Kid1412 Nope. UTF-8 is just one of the **many** ways to encode unicode. You need to read the article I linked as you have plenty misconceptions. | If that DB is normally accessed via a Web Portal, it might even use a propietary format. Something totally unreleated to anything you find on Wikipedia. Unless you know the file type with absolute certainty, there is no way for you to transfer this data reliably.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have tried and this is .ZIP file, not images :( Thanks again!